# Python Dateutil Parsing: Minimum number of components

Tags: python, python-dateutil

The python `dateutils` package allows to parse date(time)s without specifying a format. It attempts to always return a date, even when the input does not appear to be one (e.g. `12`). What would be a pythonic way to ensure at least a day, month and year component to be present in the input?

```
from dateutil import parser

dstr = '12'
dtime = parser.parse(dstr)
```

Returns
`2019-06-12 00:00:00`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way you could do it is by splitting the input string on the likely date delimiters (e.g., `.`, `-`, `:`).  So, this way you could input `2016.5.19` or `2016-5-19`.

```
from dateutil import parser
import re

def date_parser(thestring):

    pieces = re.split('\.|-|:', thestring)

    if len(pieces) < 3:
        raise Exception('Must have at least year, month and date passed')

    return parser.parse(thestring)

print('---')
thedate = date_parser('2019-6-12')
print(thedate)

print('---')
thedate = date_parser('12')
print(thedate)
```

This will output:

```
---
2019-06-12 00:00:00
---
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bob.py", line 18, in <module>
    thedate = date_parser('12')
  File "bob.py", line 9, in date_parser
    raise Exception('Must have at least year, month and date passed')
Exception: Must have at least year, month and date passed
```

So the first one passes are there are 3 "pieces" to the date.  The second one doesn't.

This will get dodgy depending on what is in the `re.split`, one will have to make sure all the right delimiters are in there.

You could remove the `:` in the delimiters if you want just *typical* date delimiters.